# Deserialize json to type T

Tags: json, c#-4.0

My class calls a web service that comes back with the following structure

```
    [DataContract]
    public class ResponseClassContainer
    {
        [DataMember]
        public ResponseClass d { get; set; }
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class ResponseClass
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ResponseCode { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public object Response { get; set; }
    }
```

The container is required as the returned json returns {"d":{....}}

If the service returns success, the object Response is filled with whatever object was called as serialised json.

The problem is public object Response. As it is an object, it can be pretty much anything, but I've found that I have to explicitly say it is of type foo

```
[DataMember]
public foo Response {get;set;}
```

As I can be deserialising a whole pile of classes, is there a way that I can have

```
[DataMember]
public T Response {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have

```
[DataMember]
public BaseResponse Response { get; set; }
```

where BaseResponse is class like

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Child1))]
[KnownType(typeof(Child2))]
public class BaseResponse
```

and Child1/Child2 are classes like

```
[DataContract]
public class Child1 :  BaseResponse
```

Comment: Thanks - for the BaseResponse class, what do I need in there? It is going to be a huge class if I have to add in every type from the Child classes!